# C# multiple selection listbox move

Tags: c#

What I have is two listboxs.

In listbox1 I want the user to be able to click a button and move all selected items to listbox two.  Also if there is nothing selected i dont want the button to work.  Anybody have any suggestions?

listbox1.items.add(listbox2.selecteditems); just moves over (collection) to the 2nd listbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you will need to move the items separately:

```
List<object> itemsToRemove = new List<object>();

foreach (var item in listbox2.SelectedItems)
{
    listbox1.Items.Add(item);
    itemsToRemove.Add(item);
}

foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
{
    listbox2.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

This will move any selected items from `listbox2` to `listbox1`. The `itemsToRemove` list is used as a temporary storage since you cannot modify a collection while iterating over it; while iterating we just add references to the items to be removed into a temporary list, then we iterate over that list and remove the items.

In order to handle the case when no items are selected, I would set up an event handler for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, and set the `Enabled` property of the button:

```
theButton.Enabled = (listbox2.SelectedItems.Count > 0);
```

Comment: Good call, I forgot to remove them from the original list.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using Linq:

```
private void buttonMove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<object>().ToArray())
    {
        listBox1.Items.Remove(item);
        listBox2.Items.Add(item);
    }
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonMove.Enabled = listBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, The `.ToArray()` is important so you're not modifying the collection during the `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

for Winforms:

```
foreach (var i in listbox1.SelectedItems) {
     listbox2.SelectedItems.add(i);
}
```

To enable the button only when necessary add code to the `OnSelectionChanged` event and set `button1.enabled = (Listbox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0);`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (listbox1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
{
    return;
}

// Do this if you want to clear the second ListBox
listbox2.Items.Clear();

foreach (object obj in listbox1.SelectedItems)
{
    listbox2.Items.Add(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Listbox1 use the SelectedItemChanged Event and use your EventArgs provided to get the selected item -> then add to listbox2.

If no item is selected button.enbabled = false;